# Android USB Host - Why is a thumb drive visible while another Mass Storage Device is hidden?

Tags: android, usb

I am trying to connect an android phone to a usb device in order to read a file from the device. The phone has USB Host (Galaxy S4) and I am using a USB OTG cable. I notice that when I connect a thumb drive, the device becomes visible and I can browse its files in Astro File Manager. I can also access its contents programmatically:

```
File f = new File("/storage/UsbDriveA/");
String[] files = f.list();
for (String s : files) {
    logger.d("File name: " + s);
}
```

However, with the other usb device, I cannot see it in Astro File Manager or access it programmatically. I used USB Device Info to compare the profiles of the two USB devices. Both are Mass Storage Devices and have similar profiles. Here are a couple screen shots comparing the two profiles:

[image: USB profile of thumb drive]

[image: USB profile of other device]

In addition, both devices are visible when using UsbManager's getDeviceList. However, I don't know if UsbDeviceCommunication is what I am looking for. It is used for sending and receiving messages, while I need to only grab a file.

So, I have two questions:

1. What is different about the two usb devices that causes the thumb drive to be accessible and the other to be hidden?
2. Am I correct that UsbDeviceCommunication is not what I am looking for? If it is, how can I use it to read a specific file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by Chris Stratton in the comments, the issue had nothing to do with OTG. The device I was trying to read was a FAT12 File System, which was unsupported by that phone.

---

Well after reaching out to an engineer in the company that produces the device with which I was trying to connect, I finally have an answer. USB OTG is an extension of the USB protocol. If the device does not support the OTG extension (which this particular device did not) and those extensions are needed by the USB mass storage drivers on Android, then the usb device will not be successfully enumerated by the host.

Comment: This is probably not the answer.  Typically Android devices don't go into host mode as a result of the *peripheral* "supporting" OTG, but rather because your adapter cable for getting from a micro USB plug to a full size USB A socket internally grounds the OTG mode pin.  More likely there is a difference of the partition table details or file system on your second device which make the manufacturer unique service or daemon which mounted the first device decide it doesn't know what to do with the second.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Late reply, but you were spot on. The phone did not recognize the device, because its file system was FAT12.

Comment: No, that is probably NOT the reason.  Generally speaking, an Android device will only recognize a peripheral if it is connected via a USB adapter that grounds the OTG ID pin. Of course, stock Android has not traditionally supported filesystems on USB drives at all, leaving the implementation of support for such up to apps or vendor modifications.